# FBSDKLoginMangerLoginResult, NSError Swift 7.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, xcode7.3

I am trying to use the doc's firebase provides. Maybe I converted it wrong from obj. C. Please see below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    facebookLoginBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.facebookLoginBtnPress), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}

    // MARK Facebook btn pressed
    @IBAction func facebookLoginBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) {

    let login = FBSDKLoginManager()

    login.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: {(facebookResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult, facebookError: NSError?) -> Void in

        if facebookError != nil {

        } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
        }
    })

}
```

This is the obj. C

```
// Handle clicks on the button
[myLoginButton 
 addTarget:self 
 action:@selector(loginButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Once the button is clicked, show the login dialog
-(void)loginButtonClicked
{
 FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
 [login
   logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
      fromViewController:self
                 handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) { 
       NSLog(@"Process error");
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
       NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    } else {
       NSLog(@"Logged in");
    }
  }];
}
```

This is the error

Cannot convert value of type '(FBSDKLoginMangerLoginResult, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type 'FBSDKLoginMangerRequestTokenHandler!'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// use this method in login with fb butn
-(void)loginWithFbBtnMethode
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
{
    NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);
    [self fetchUserInfo];
}
else
{
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             [self.view makeToast:@"Login process error" duration:2.0 position:@"center"];
             NSLog(@"Login process error");
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             [self.view makeToast:@"User cancelled login" duration:2.0 position:@"center"];
             NSLog(@"User cancelled login");
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Login Success");
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                [self fetchUserInfo];
             }
             else
             {
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

}

//user details getting method

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was just looking and I just forced unwrapped the FBSDKLoginMangerLoginResult  not sure if this is good practice but it works now.  ​

Answer (score 0):

I got also so many errors in 7.3.1 when use fb or gmail and creating in developer certificates so try to downgrade to 7.2.1 it is fine to anywhere.